# How to pass directives to snappy_ec2 created clusters

Tags: snappydata

We have a need to set some directives in the snappy config files for the various components (servers, locators, etc).

The `snappy_ec2` scripts do a good job at creating all of the config's and keeping them in sync across the cluster, but I need to find a serviceable method to add directives to the auto generated scripts.

What is the preferred method using this script?

> Example: Add the following to the 'servers' file:
>   -gemfirexd.disable-getall-local-index=true

Or perhaps I should add these strings to an environments file such as 
`snappy-env.sh`

TIA

-doug

Comment: Hi doug, will get this answered for you asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the directives directly in the servers (or locators or leads) file and placing this file under (SNAPPY_DIR)/ec2/deploy/home/ec2-user/snappydata/? The script would read the conf files under this dir at the time of launching the cluster.

You'll need to specify it for each server you want to launch, with the name of server as shown below. See 'Specifying properties' section in [README](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata/blob/master/docs/snappyOnAWS.md), if you have not already done so. e.g.

```
{{SERVER_0}} -heap-size=4096m -locators={{LOCATOR_0}}:9999,{{LOCATOR_1}}:9888 -J-Dgemfirexd.disable-getall-local-index=true
{{SERVER_1}} -heap-size=4096m -locators={{LOCATOR_0}}:9999,{{LOCATOR_1}}:9888 -J-Dgemfirexd.disable-getall-local-index=true
```

If you want it to be applied for all the servers, simply put it in snappy-env.sh as you mentioned (as SERVER_STARTUP_OPTIONS) and place the file under directory mentioned above.

We could have read the conf files directly from (SNAPPY_DIR)/conf/ instead of making users copy it to above location, but we may release the ec2 scripts as a separate package, in future, so that the users do not have to download the entire distribution.

Comment: I had completely missed that section when I read the readme. 

So in reality, when using the ec2 automation scripts, there's a bit of manual pre-processing of the config files? I understand these are still under development, so it's not ideal.

Perhaps updating the  snappy-ec2 shell wrapper to generate the conf files prior to calling the python script would be a good work around. 

Do you see any problem with that approach?

Comment: Yes, to use non-default properties, user needs to specify those via conf files.

Comment: Hit submit accidentally.
Good suggestion, thanks. Yes, we could enhance that part of the script. Filed a JIRA to track it (https://jira.snappydata.io/browse/SNAP-984)